# Define user-function to add/subtract from tibble

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I'm trying to write a function that will nudge nodes in a graph that works with layout matrices in R. I'm working with `ggraph` primarily, so having it be `dplyr`-esque is important.

My function works well when I want to nudge in positive directions, but does not for negative directions. I've tried wrapping parathesis around the arguments, but it does not seem to work. Any ideas? Here is an example:

Generate a layout matrix suitable for most graphing packages in R.

```
set.seed(123)
layout <- matrix(nrow = 5, ncol = 2, sample(seq(0, 1, .1), 10, T))
```

Define my user-function, which takes a `matrix`, converts it to a `tibble`, then uses `mutate` and `ifelse`.

```
layout_nudge <- function(layout., 
                         node. = 1, 
                         x. = 0, 
                         y. = 0){
  as.tibble(layout.) %>%
    set_names('x.', 'y.') %>% 
    mutate(id = row_number(),
           x. = ifelse(id == node., x. + x, x.), 
           y. = ifelse(id == node., y. + y, y.))
}

## ADDITION
# Works
 # Convert to a tibble,
 # For node 1, add 1 to column x
 # For node 1, add 1 to column y
layout_nudge(layout, 1, 1, 1)


# A tibble: 5 x 3
     x.    y.    id
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1   1.9   0.7     1
2   0.7   0.5     2
3   0.7   0.6     3
4   1     0.3     4
5   0.7   0.1     5


## SUBTRACTION
# Does not work
 # Convert to a tibble,
 # For node 1, subtract 1 from column x
 # For node 1, subtract 1 from column y
layout_nudge(layout, 1, -1, -1) 

# A tibble: 5 x 3
     x.    y.    id
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1   1.9   0.7     1
2   0.7   0.5     2
3   0.7   0.6     3
4   1     0.3     4
5   0.7   0.1     5
```

Comment: did you maybe mean to use `x` and `y` as function parameters instead of `x.`and `y.`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can't reproduce your problem. Works quite fine if I edit the function like (`x.` und `y.` in the function header has been changed to `x1` resp. `y1`)

```
layout_nudge <- function(layout., 
                         node. = 1, 
                         x1 = 0, 
                         y1 = 0){
  as.tibble(layout.) %>%
    set_names('x.', 'y.') %>% 
    mutate(id = row_number(),
           x. = ifelse(id == node., x. + x1, x.), 
           y. = ifelse(id == node., y. + y1, y.))
}
```

Comment: You're right. I don't know why that is? Hmmm. Thanks.